# Worker Allocation in House Building Optimisation

Tags: cplex, opl, cp-optimizer

As part of my thesis project, I was given a house building problem. There are 17 tasks in total and some tasks need to be completed before others. There are also 5 different worker types (builder, architect etc) and each task requires different types and amount of workers.

I am complete beginner in CPLEX OPL and using the tutorials provided, I was able to minimise the time taken to complete the 17 tasks. I used `dvar intervals` and `endBeforeStart()` for this purpose. However, I have spent countless hours trying to add workers to my problem with no success. The examples only include workers with names; but in my problem I have different types of workers which the tasks require, and each type has a different number of workers available.

How can I add workers to my problem and allocate them to each task in an optimal way?

Answer (score 1):

I have answered [this elsewhere](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=8d132513-1694-4a66-868f-9b4a676640d2&ps=25):

> You could have a look at the example at `CPLEX_Studio128\opl\examples\opl\sched_cumul`
>
> And instead of one cumul
>
> ```
> cumulFunction workersUsage =
> ```
>
> you could use several (One per type of workers)